# Json returns empty string between tags

Tags: php, json, string, yii

i am new to json and i have a problem that why json_decode returns empty string between tags of < and > ...
here is my json string

```
{
    "clipboard": 
    {

    "title": " Mozilla Firefox ",
    "event": "<MOUSE+Copy/Paste>"
     }
 }
```

the output from json_decode through var_dump shows

```
    object(stdClass)#44 (1) { ["clipboard"]=> object(stdClass)#45 (2) { ["title"]=> string(17) " Mozilla Firefox " ["event"]=> string(18) "" } }
```

Why it keeps removing data between the "<" and ">" , i checked on an online json editor it validate my json string successfully and it does shows the value as it is. But when i use deocde_json the "event" array element comes empty.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. It [runs fine](http://codepad.org/na6bgDJK) on my end. Are you sure that that's your json string?

Comment: i am posting json data through POST do you think is it because of that? For e.g. i made a small page with textarea it takes the json code and then i call json_decode

Comment: i think i got the error its because yii post query is automatically removing this thanks for mentioning me your result it helped me to find out my silly problem.

Comment: No yii post query does not remove it because the var_dump of the json prints a length of 18 for your event string. Look at my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `string(18)` in `["event"]=> string(18) ""` gives you a clue.

Look at the source of your page. It is not displayed on your website but in the source because it is interpreted like an html tag.

Comment: Nice eyes! I completely let that one pass right by. +999 if I could.

Comment: absolutely 101% right , when i checked the source of html on the output it showed me the exact string i was having in json code. Though it is not displaying it on the page which is obvious that it took it as an html for displaying page...Thanks a lot ..